# passing data via ajax to php and returning

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a basic form if the user needs to reset their email in forgotForm.php:

```
<script src="js/forgotPwd.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 ..... <edited for brevity> .....

<form class="forgot active" id="forgotPwdForm" method="post" action="#" autocomplete="off" >
    <h2>Reset Password</h2>

    <div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email"  placeholder="Email" required />
    </div>

    <div>
        <legend><span id="spambot">Are you human?</span></legend>
        <input id="num1" name="num1" readonly="readonly" class="sum" value="<?php echo rand(1,4) ?>" /> + 
        <input id="num2" name="num2" readonly="readonly" class="sum" value="<?php echo rand(5,9) ?>" /> =
        <input id="captcha" name="captcha"  class="captcha" maxlength="2" required />
    </div>


    <div class="bottom">
        <button type="submit" class="button-blue" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <div class="messagebox">
            <div class="alert-message"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

forgotPwd.js is this:

```
 $("#forgotPwdForm").submit(function() {
        if ($("#forgotPwdForm").valid()) {
            var data = $('#forgotPwdForm').serialize();
            console.log(data);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process_forgotPwd.php",
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                    if (msg.result == 1) {
                        $('.messagebox').addClass("success-message");
                        $('.message').slideDown('slow');
                        $('.alert-message').text("Sending reset pwd email ...");
                        $('#forgotPwdForm').fadeOut(5000);
                        window.location = "success.php";
                    } else {
                        $('.messagebox').hide();
                        $('.messagebox').addClass("error-message");
                        $('.alert-message').html(msg.result);
                        $('.messagebox').slideDown('slow');
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('Error: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
                  }
            });
             return false;
        }

    });
```

This data is output to the console, which looks fine to me:

```
email=johndoe%40gmail.com&num1=2&num2=6&captcha=8
```

Which is exactly what I've entered on the form.  In "process_forgotPwd.php" I run server-side validation, then send the user an email with a reset link (which they get with no problem).  At the bottom of "process_forgotPwd.php" I send back a status, depending on whether or not the email was sent correctly:

```
if (!$mail->Send()) {
    echo json_encode(array('result' => $msg_email_error));
    die();
} else {;
    //header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
    echo json_encode(array('result' => 1));
    exit();
    }
```

(Someone suggested the header line which I tried to no avail).  When control is returned to forgotPwd.js, it throws this error:

```
Error: parsererror SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Yet my data looks fine to me. What am I missing?

Error: parsererror SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: would you see the result console.log(msg);? just before if (msg.result == 1) {

Comment: No I don't. I also just printed out:                          `error_log(print_r(array('result' => 1))); `    in my php file and it prints a 1.

Comment: would you remove the exit(); function , it completely close the application

Comment: Tried that - no difference.  If everything is successful, it seems as though the "1" does not get passed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `dataType: "json",` to `dataType: "text",`. The data returned by your server is not valid JSON. The `dataType` setting **is not for the data you're sending to the server but rather for what the server returns, which means the parse error is referring to `msg` not `data`**

Let the only statement in the `success` callback be:

```
console.log( msg );
```

Once you've confirmed the structure of the data being returned, update your logic in the `success` handler and the `dataType` value accordingly.

Comment: ok... almost there I think. I changed the dataType to text, and in the console I get the following:

    `Content: 
    SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220-box.xxxx.com ESMTP Exim 4.82 #2 Wed, 23 Jul 2014 16:11:29 -0600 
    ...... 
     <br />SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 OK id=1XA4l0-0005ol-Aw
     <br />{"result":1}`

Why am I getting the return from smtp email along with the result I want?

Comment: @KathyL time to take a look at your PHP script. That's where all that is coming from.

Comment: Yep, just realized that - had a problem posting.  Took off the SMTP debug message, and I am returning 1 if the email was sent successfully vice `json_encode`.  Thank you!